# How to specify unlimited children in a DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

I have a root tag `<alphabet>` which can have an unlimited (but optional) number of tags `<a>` or `<b>` or `<c>` in them.  How do I specify this in a DTD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `*` occurrence indicator:

```
<!ELEMENT alphabet (a|b|c)*>
```

You could also use `ANY` if you don't know what children `alphabet` will have:

```
<!ELEMENT alphabet ANY>
```

Note that whatever elements (tags) that appear inside of `alphabet` still need to be declared. [See my answer here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489366/how-to-add-dtd-element-if-i-dont-know-the-child-elements/6496529#6496529).